# Tensorflow can't handle multiple input

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras

Have one model to proccess image and one model to proccess numerical values.
Merged both models getting this:
[Merged model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JC9Eh.png)

For the image input I created a image data generator from a dataframe + pictures:

```
print('Importing keras...')
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

print('Defining datagens and dataflows...')

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255.,
                                   rotation_range = 25,
                                   width_shift_range = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
                                   height_shift_range = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   channel_shift_range = 0.3,
                                   horizontal_flip = True,
                                   vertical_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator( rescale = 1.0/255. )

# Flow training images batch size should consider RAM
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=df_train_img,
                                                    directory='/kaggle/input/siim-isic-melanoma-classification/jpeg/train',
                                                    x_col = 'image_name',
                                                    y_col = 'benign_malignant',
                                                    batch_size = 20,
                                                    class_mode = 'binary', 
                                                    target_size = (256, 256))     

# Flow validation images batch size should consider RAM
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=df_test_img,
                                                    directory='/kaggle/input/siim-isic-melanoma-classification/jpeg/train',
                                                    x_col = 'image_name',
                                                    y_col = 'benign_malignant',
                                                    batch_size = 20,
                                                    class_mode = 'binary', 
                                                    target_size = (256, 256))

print('Done')
```

For the numerical part I created a dataframe with features:

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hh1la.png)

Compiled the model:

```
img_model = keras.Sequential([
  layers.Flatten(input_shape=(256, 256, 3)),
  layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(12, activation='softmax')
])

# Flatten the output layer to 1 dimension
reg_model = keras.Sequential([
  layers.Flatten(input_shape=(12, )),
  layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(12, activation='softmax')
])

z = layers.concatenate([img_model.output,reg_model.output])
# Flatten the output layer to 1 dimension
z = layers.Flatten()(z)
# Add a fully connected layer with 1,024 hidden units and ReLU activation
z = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(z)
# Add a dropout rate of 0.2
z = layers.Dropout(0.2)(z)                  
# Add a final sigmoid layer for classification
z = layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')(z)


model = Model( inputs=[reg_model.input, img_model.input], outputs=z) 

model.compile(optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.0001), 
              loss = 'binary_crossentropy', 
              metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

And when I tried to fit:

```
history = model.fit(
            {'flatten_15_input':train_generator,'flatten_16_input':X_train},
            {'dense_31' : y_train},
            epochs = 2,
            verbose = 2)
```

Got the following error:

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'dict'> containing {"<class 'str'>"} keys and {"<class 'keras_preprocessing.image.dataframe_iterator.DataFrameIterator'>", "<class 'numpy.ndarray'>"} values), (<class 'dict'> containing {"<class 'str'>"} keys and {"<class 'numpy.ndarray'>"} values)
```

Tried to pass as input a dataframe, an array and a dataset.
Each model works fine before the merge. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the fit method you should pass list of inputs instead of a dict. Same thing for the output. Your code should look like this

```py
history = model.fit(
            [train_generator, X_train],
            y_train,
            epochs = 2,
            verbose = 2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it gave me the same output. I tried that way first and went for the dict to try to solve following this: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional

Comment: I think the problem might be caused by fact, that one input comes from generator, while the second straight from array. One solution might be to create generator that merges these two inputs and use it in `model.fit_generator`.

Comment: I think that may be the problem too, but I do have 2 inputs in the model, how would the fit function know which part of the custom generator would be into one input and which one would be into another? I would appreciate any examples. By the way, I tried transforming the dataframe into dataset and set the same batch size for both, but had no success...
Also, this link here has a similar input:
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/02/04/keras-multiple-inputs-and-mixed-data/

Comment: Just noticed in the link the images are not into a generator, but into an array. Will try converting the image part to an array. I'm worried about RAM though...